# How to write set of words in single cell of CSV file from python list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

```
dataList = ['#cyclone', '#twister', '#thunderstorm', '#supercell', '#wind', '#weatherradar', '#storm', '#waterspout', '#tropicalcyclone', '#hurricane', '#typhoon', '#snowstorm']
    with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(dataList)
```

Above code is writing each word of list to a new cell in CSV file but,
I want to this list's data written as 5 words per cell in a single row. Can someone please suggest me solution or can write piece of code or correct this one?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: in the above snippet I'm trying to write words from above data-list to CSV file and format should be 5 words per cell in a single row.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see that you are doing anything other than writing it all out to one row. Have you tried a loop?

Comment: nope no yet tried. will it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a naive solution for this, you could modify it to better fit your uses. It goes as follows:

```
import csv
dataList = ['#cyclone', '#twister', '#thunderstorm', '#supercell', '#wind', '#weatherradar', '#storm', '#waterspout', '#tropicalcyclone', '#hurricane', '#typhoon', '#snowstorm']
with open("Output.csv","w") as Output_csv:
    CSVWriter = csv.writer(Output_csv, delimiter = ' ')
    CSVWriter.writerow(dataList[:5])
    CSVWriter.writerow(dataList[5:10])
    CSVWriter.writerow(dataList[10:12])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah its working but adding words for new range e.g., [5:10] in new list. But great hint will try to modify accordingly. Thanks