# How to write atleast 5 words in single cell of CSV file from python list? I've posted the required solution

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

```
dataList = ['#cyclone', '#twister', '#thunderstorm', '#supercell', '#wind', '#weatherradar', '#storm', '#waterspout', '#tropicalcyclone', '#hurricane', '#typhoon', '#snowstorm']
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(dataList)
```

How to write set of words in single cell of CSV file from python list?
Above code is writing each word of list to a new cell in CSV file but,
I want to this list's data written as 5 words per cell in a single row. Can someone please suggest me solution or can write piece of code or correct this one pleaseeeeeeeeeee? will be grateful.

Comment: Small change; `writer.writerow([' '.join(dataList)])`

Comment: yeah that's working but this change pushes all me list into a single cell.

Comment: Ah, I see. You may want to chunk `dataList` into groups of 5, iterate over each group and run the join code above.

Comment: yeah will try thanks :)

Comment: @MuhammadHamaadLatif, I have updated my answer with correct code, Sorry initially I was not pretty clear with the expected output.

Comment: If you not find the exact solution, then can you update your expected output from the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write set of words in single cell of CSV file from python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299870/how-to-write-set-of-words-in-single-cell-of-csv-file-from-python-list)

Comment: words(1-5 in 1st cell),words(6-10 in 2nd cell) and so on. This should be done in a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing changing cells i've used 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
and Thanks COLD SPEED and Vivek for helping to open my vision regarding this issue :)
Though looping and making string of 5 words each is not good approach but so far its better because this have solved my issue

```
 import csv
    dataList = ['#cyclone', '#twister', '#thunderstorm', '#supercell', '#wind', '#weatherradar', '#storm', '#waterspout', '#tropicalcyclone', '#hurricane', '#typhoon', '#snowstorm']
        l=0
        t=0
        myRequiredResult=[]
            while t<dataList.__len__():
                if t % 5 == 0:
                   l = l+1
                   myRequiredResult.append("")
                myRequiredResult[l]=myRequiredResul[l]+" "+dataList[t]
                t=t+1

            with open('test.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fp:
                writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                writer.writerow(myRequiredResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a loop as below.

```
import csv
dataList = ['#cyclone', '#twister', '#thunderstorm', '#supercell', '#wind', '#weatherradar', '#storm', '#waterspout', '#tropicalcyclone', '#hurricane', '#typhoon', '#snowstorm']
x=""
for i in range(0, len(dataList),5):
 x=x+''.join(map(str,dataList[i:i + 5]))
 if len(dataList[i:i + 5]) >4 and i%5 == 0:
  x=x+"|"
file = open('test.csv', 'w')
file.write(x)
```

Written CSV contains:

```
[vivek@centosnode1 python]$ cat test.csv
#cyclone#twister#thunderstorm#supercell#wind|#weatherradar#storm#waterspout#tropicalcyclone#hurricane|#typhoon#snowstorm
```

Comment: This isn't what was asked. They want to write 5 words at a time.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, You may remove the downvote, that time I was not pretty clear about expected output.

Comment: I just thought, but don't mind Please. Is my new answer is up to the mark?

Comment: Not yet, those words still go into individual cells, not a single one.

Comment: Individual cell mean, I did’t understand can u plz clear me

Comment: 5 words in a single column.

Comment: yeah 5 words per cell in single row----> expected output format should be as follows...  |words 1-5|   |words 5-10| |words 11-15| and so on

Comment: I have updated the answer with expected output, let me know if there is any changes.

Comment: result was still going into a single cell.

Comment: If u are opening the file in excel then you have to change some settings like it should take the line delimited by | try this if it is not working then please let me know